# Proving bijectivity of $f_\sigma$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Let $\sigma\in S_n$ be a permutation and we set $S:=\{(i,j)\in \{1,\dots,n\}^2:i<j\}$. We would like to prove that the map
$$f_\sigma:S\longrightarrow S,\quad (i,j)\longmapsto \begin{cases}
(\sigma(i),\sigma(j)), & \text{ if } \sigma(i)<\sigma(j),\\
(\sigma(j),\sigma(i)), & \text{ if } \sigma(i)>\sigma(j).
\end{cases}$$
is bijective. If we show injectivity, as we work on a finite set, we are done.

Well, let's take $(i,j),(k,l)\in S$ with $f_\sigma(i,j)= f_\sigma(k,l)$. If $\sigma(i)<\sigma(j)$ and $\sigma(k)<\sigma(l)$, then $\sigma(i)=\sigma(k)$ and $\sigma(j)=\sigma(l)$, so $(i,j)=(k,l)$, since  $\sigma$ is invertible.

Now, if $\sigma(i)<\sigma(j)$ and $\sigma(k)>\sigma(l)$? Then $f_\sigma(i,j)=f_\sigma(k,l)$ means that $(i,j)=(l,k)$. Since $i<j$, it must be $l<k$, contradiction. The same happens if
$\sigma(i)>\sigma(j)$ and $\sigma(k)<\sigma(l)$.

Lastly, if $\sigma(i)>\sigma(j)$ and $\sigma(k)>\sigma(l)$, we work as the first case.

Is that correct?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I modified a bit the question, hoping now is clearer.

Comment: For the case you mention, it can be processed by the property of $S$: $i<j$.
And I think you can consider the quotient transformation on $\mathbb{Z}_n\times \mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: Or you can consider to prove surjectivity first.

Comment: You mean that since $l<k$ and $(k, l) \in S$, then exactly by the property you mentioned this is not possible. Right?

Comment: I think it more straightforward to find an inverse. If $(a,b) = f_\sigma(i,j)$ then exactly one of
$(\sigma^{-1}(a), \sigma^{-1}(b)), (\sigma^{-1}(b), \sigma^{-1}(a)) \in S$, which completely specifies $(i,j)$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, this seems to be good way to tackle. However, would you agree with my argument? :)